# Paypal API - get all subscriptions by subscriber

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

There is an API call to find the subscription details etc, but what if I want to check all the subscriptions that a user has purchased? There's no API for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. One of your users could have activated subscriptions with different payer accounts -- or a payer account could have been used to activate multiple users. It's not a 1:1 relationship (unless you were to enforce it) so you need to track this information in your own database.

Comment: I see. What if the server was down when the webhook was called? Will it retry?

Comment: Info is at https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#link-messages , it will retry up to 25 times over the course of 3 days until it receives an HTTP 2xx response